# Is there an example of the system of euclidean geometry being applied outside the context of visual geometry?

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry

I've read about formal systems. I've read about how axioms and definitions are just treated as 'abstract entities'/ words. This made me wonder, is there an example of the system of euclidean geometry being applied to things other than visual lines and points? If not, then what does it mean that the axioms and definition are just "abstract entities"?

Comment: Euclidean geometry was used in Newton's Principia.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Finite geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometry) may give you some ideas.